# Dual-role keys on linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

I want to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as a dual-role key, for instance with the following two functions:

1. normal <kbd>Shift</kbd>, e.g. left <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> results in capital 'T'
2. as a <kbd>\</kbd> key, i.e. if pressed and released without any additional key, it should print '\'.

Another example would be [*SandS*, <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key#Dual-role_keys) .

Is that possible in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xcape (https://github.com/alols/xcape) allows to use modifier keys as shortcuts. the program runs as a daemon and should be auto-started in some way.

the syntax is simple, in my case it is

```
xcape -t 200 -e 'Shift_L=backslash;Shift_R=End'
```

symbols can be taken from http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap, modifiers are the ones in `xmodmap -pm` (i suppose).

note that the daemon does not communicate to other instances, so in order to edit the setting, one has to kill the old one.

there is a forked package called ksuperkey, it's identical up to the default setting and an kde autostart file, which was used to kick of the kde menu. at the moment it seems like there are more ready-made packages for ksuperkey (tinyurl.com/jcagjxv), but in the future that might change, because it'll be replaced by an implementation in the kde window manager itself (tinyurl.com/hcbku6b)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only  for X and not real terminal, you need to play with xev and xmodmap (install it if aren't in your default distro), those changes will dissapear after X logout, so you can persist them under your desktop init script configs.

Please check the answer found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices

You can't easily remap keys on terminal because will follow keyboard map files from /usr/share/locale/* and isn't quite easy to modify, also, X uses a different keyboard mapping, but supports both usermode and system override of that. xev and xmodpam are user mode modifications, but you can create a xorg script at /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ under a InputClass section.

Hope it helps to solve your question!

Comment: please forgive me if i missed something, but the link does not explain how to make dual role keys.

Comment: in particular: i've seen that it's possible to add the shift function to any key. so i tried to set the shift key to '/'. now, when i press shift t, it prints '/T'. that is not what i want.

Comment: Oh my bad, you need to set a dead key, so you can use it as combo key (like control, alt and shift).

Comment: What the link say, you can start xev, press your combo keys with a dead key (ctrl+u, ctrl-k... etc), get the combination key code, and then do remapping of that keycode with xmodmap to do something other key

Comment: ok, i googled, but i could not find how to make shift a dead key

Comment: and i can't parse the comment with xev, combo keys and remapping. but I understand how xev and simple remapping in xmodmap works :)

Comment: Can you try doing some testing using the a Keyboard Layout with AltGr dead key, then remmapping AltGr to do something. For example, you can remmap accents with your desired key (instead å -> ^), or you want to remmap more of 1 character? That may need extra work.

Comment: how can i get a keyboard layout with AltGr dead key?

Comment: If you have a systemd based system, you can use localectl to check your current config, check available keyboards, layouts and set the configurations for both terminal and X11. Arch explains this better with examples: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Setting_keyboard_layout   Also, you can change it using your Desktop Environment, like KDE or Gnome. I don't have much experience with LXCE or others.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/1120732/644966 seems like there is no AltGr dead key layout for localectl. I found some AltGr deadkey layouts here: http://askubuntu.com/a/110848, but i think those work in some other way.

Comment: That link shows keymaps, but you need variants, a modified/alternative version of the keymap. Keymaps on X are classified as layout and variants, where layout may be your physical keyboard configuration, and variant how you want to use it. Try with `localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts` to find your keyboard, then `localectl list-x11-keymap-variants us` for US example and you may see the keyboards. alt-intl and altgr-intl are for alt deadkey for example.

Comment: ah, i missed those.
anyway, i have a different solution now. i'll post in a sec..

Answer (score 0):

For those interested to have a "dual key" function **without** X, only on the CLI (Command Line Interface), there is a solution to use an appropriate keyboard. The advantage is that e.g. a dual key  SPACE = CONTROL (if pressed together with another key) will work on all other OSs-computers you plug it in (MacOs, Windows, Linux...).
For example  the`[UHK Keyboard can do this as part of their "UHK Agent" configuration software.][1]` ( I am **not** affiliated with this company.)
I just think this is a very straight forward solution. I have no knowledge of implementing a "dual role key" on the Command line Interface in Linux, and it seems there is non. At least not without much headache and tinkering.